# PHP Wordpress code echo's slug not term?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-fields

Does anybody know how I can change the below code for my custom taxonomy (created in the Magic Fields 2 plugin) to solve my problem. I would like it to echo the `name` of the selected value rather than `slug` format. e.g. I'd like to echo `Client 1` and `Client 2` instead of `client-1` and `client-2` as it currently does.

I'd like to display multiword names with spaces and correct capitalisation e.g. `Joe Bloggs Associates` not `joe-bloggs-associates`.

`project_statistics_client` is the name of the field created in Magic Fields. The Type of the custom field is `Term` dropdown and populates with the values from my custom Taxonomy called `Clients`. This field is located inside of a field group that's named `project_statistics` but I am not sure if the group name influences the code or not?

Also please note that all the above is in a custom post type called `Projects`.

I have checked [plugin](http://wiki.magicfields.org/doku.php?id=magic_fields_v2.0) help but still not sure:

Here is the code:

```
<?php $clients = get_field('project_statistics_client');
    foreach($clients as $client){
        echo '<div>' . $client . '</div>';
    } ?>
```

Comment: I was wondering whether adding $client->name would help. The slugs disappear, no errors appear but nothings displays? Using echo get_label('project_statistics_client'); successfully returns the label of the field and so I wonder if it's a different get_ to return the name rather than slug? Can't find the answer anywhere, been searching all over the web.

Comment: Using _get('field_name'); seems to work on everything else I have tried, it looks like it's only the 'custom taxonomy' values that display as slugs when you populate a term field with them. Under the Magic Fields plugin settings I cannot see a way to set taxonomies to display as the 'name' rather than 'slug', this option doesn't look present in both the custom taxonomy list itself or the Term dropdown menu that is used to show these values.? I'm sure there is a relatively simple answer, I just cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    global $post;
    $taxonomy = 'your taxonomy';
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
    if ( is_array($terms) ) {
        echo(implode(',', wp_list_pluck($terms, 'name')));
    }
```

Magic Fields 2 only provides a nice GUI to the basic WordPress taxomony feature and therefore all the WordPress taxonomy functions can be used. In particular, get_the_terms() may be used to get the categories of a post. This returns an array of objects (a post may be in multiple categories). Also, you need to extract the 'name' field from the objects.

Comment: Hey Magenta, thanks for your feedback. That's good that all the standard Wordpress Taxonomy functions can be used. Is this true even when using a custom post type? I tried the code you kindly supplied above wrapped in PHP tags because it was echoing the code, it doesn't error but it's not displaying the array of terms. The page displays with other elements but where the array should be there's nothing? I have put this inside my template page in the loop. Is that correct? I changed 'your taxonomy' to be 'project_statistics_client' and 'name' I kept as 'name'.

Comment: WordPress taxonomy functions work with custom post types. I have tested the code so I know it works. Are you using the correct taxonomy slug? Look up the taxonomy slug name on the Magic Fields page for taxonomies. Of course 'name' should be 'name'.

Comment: The taxonomy slug is shown under the column 'Type' on the Magic Fields 'Post Types' page.

Comment: Okay, the taxonomy is actually 'client', I did try that before as well, but this still is not displaying. I don't know what I have done wrong, I know your code must be right as you have tested it. I can't understand why it displays nothing, I know that the taxonomy exists because on the page I am viewing it still echos the slug versions okay. So I know they are present? It's odd. my template page is called projectLayoutA.php and I have just added the code under the loop within php tags. I am using a custom post type as well that's why asked about them. Thanks

Comment: I suspect the taxonomy doesn't exists and you are echoing something from somewhere else? On the custom post page editor in the category pane are the checkboxes for the categories actually checked? Try adding a new category using the category pane on the custom post page editor.

Comment: Magenta, you are spot on. Genius, thanks. I had been using the 'Term' select menu I created with MF (which obviously isn't working as it should) but selecting the term in the pane on the right works a treat and they display fine. Would it be easy to adapt your code to display them on their own line rather than comma separated? I've used foreach to display repeated MF fields. I'll tick your answer as final! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: $terms is an array of objects. wp_list_pluck() returns an array of names extracted from the objects in $terms. You can use foreach on this as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a little while I remembered that I had pasted some code from a forum post which has allowed me to populate the Term dropdown field with taxonomy/category options. I now think that this is where the problem lies and why it's outputting slug and not name? I have also decided to use categories rather than taxonomy because I would like to filter the loop of posts based on the selected values and from what I read this is easier to achieve with categories. I attach below the code I have added to functions.php because a) others may want to use it with Magic Fields but also b) in the hope somebody might know what I need to change in order to output name instead of slug?

```
/**
* Custom Taxonomy Dropdown
*/



// initialisation
global $mf_domain;

// class with static properties encapsulating functions for the field type

class term_field extends mf_custom_fields {

public $allow_multiple = TRUE;
public $has_properties = TRUE;

public function _update_description(){
global $mf_domain;
$this->description = __("This field allows to do relations with taxonomie terms",$mf_domain);
}

public function _options(){
global $mf_domain;

// Get the taxonomie as dropdownoption
$select = array();
$tax = get_taxonomies();
foreach($tax as $k => $v){
$select[] = $v;
}

$data = array(
 'option' => array(
    'term' => array(
      'type' => 'select',
      'id' => 'term',
      'label' => __('related taxonomy: ',$mf_domain),
      'name' => 'mf_field[option][term]',
      'default' => '',
      'options' => $select,
      'add_empty' => false,
      'description' => '',
      'value' => '',
      'div_class' => '',
      'class' => ''
    ),
  )
);
return $data;
}

public function display_field( $field, $group_index = 1, $field_index = 1 ) {
global $mf_domain;

// If is not required this field be added a None value
$notype = "";
if( !$field['required_field'] ) {
  $notype = ( !empty($field['options']['notype']) ) ? $field['options']['notype'] : __( "-- None --" , $mf_domain );
}

$output = '';

// Get the taxonomie as dropdownoption
$select = array();
$tax = get_taxonomies();
foreach($tax as $k => $v){
$select[] = $v;
}

$option_from_term_array = $field['options']['term'];
$options = get_terms($select[$option_from_term_array], array('hide_empty' => false));
$output = '<div class="mf-dropdown-box">';
$value = $field['input_value'];

$output .= sprintf('<select class="dropdown_mf" id="%s" name="%s" >',$field['input_id'],$field['input_name']);

if( $notype != "" ) {
  $output .= "<option value=''>$notype</option>";
}

foreach($options as $option) {

  $check = ($option->slug == $value) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
  $output .= sprintf('<option value="%s" %s >%s</option>',
    esc_attr($option->slug),
    $check,
    esc_attr($option->name)
  );
}
$output .= '</select>';
$output .= '</div>';

return $output;
}
}
```